Managing and customising modern Event list/page - SharePoint Online
The Event List is one thing that is very confusing in SharePoint Online and I just need some other people views and ideas on this.
My requirements

I need to be able to add new fields to the event page to capture more data.I have been told this is not possible.But i can edit the list in classic mode and add new columns/fields
What are my options if i need another event form (apart from the modern one that can't be changed).Do i just use the old form but when i try and create a new event it redirects me to the old calendar view
We don't have access to power apps but i was thinking of creating a new custom list form and pushing the data to the Event list using power automate but what happens when they want to perform an update

I'm open to ideas and want t know how people are customising using the Eventsin SharePoint Online
Thanks in Advance
